# R gWidgets embed a "rgl" 3D plot in gWidgets2 ggraphics device

Tags: r, gwidgets

Can I embed a "rgl" 3D plot in gWidgets2 ggraphics device? For example,

```
library(gWidgets2)
library(rgl)

w <- gwindow("brushing example", visible=FALSE)
g <- ggroup(cont=w)
pg <- gnotebook(cont=g, expand=TRUE)
dev1 <- ggraphics(cont=pg)

visible(w) <- TRUE

visible(dev1) <- TRUE   
plot.new()  

x <- sort(rnorm(1000))
y <- rnorm(1000)
z <- rnorm(1000) + atan2(x,y)
plot3d(x, y, z, col=rainbow(1000))
```

Can I put the 3D plot inside the gnotebook window?

Comment: I don't see how that would be done without support for `GtkGLExt` in `RGtk2`.