# R: how to embed a 3D plot created by "rgl" into "gWidgets ggraphics device“?

Tags: r, gwidgets, rgl

I created some 3D cubes with different colors by using `rgl` package. My next step is to embed the 3D plot into `ggraphics` device from the `gWidgets` package, but I have no idea how to implement it. Is there a way to implement by `gWidgets` or other package? I have read [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26558712/r-gwidgets-embed-a-rgl-3d-plot-in-gwidgets2-ggraphics-device), nobody answered the question but a comment@jverzani. Any help? Thank you in advance!

My code:

```
library(rgl)
library(scatterplot3d)
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")


df<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4),
               y=c(2,4,6,8),
               z=c(3,6,9,12),
               value=c(33,43,75,21))

clr <- df$value/max(df$value)
f <- colorRamp(c("green", "yellow", "purple", "red"))

## 3D PLOT
for(i in 1:length(df$x)){
  shade3d(translate3d(scale3d(cube3d(col=rgb(f(clr[i])/255),alpha=0.15 ),
                                     10.0, 10.0, 2.5),df$x[i],df$y[i],df$z[i]))
} 

window <- gwindow("TEST", width = 800, height= 600, visible = FALSE)
group <- ggroup(cont = window, expand = TRUE)


loadBtn <- gbutton("display", cont = group)

addHandlerChanged(loadBtn, handler = function(h,...){
  sudwin<-gwindow("3D",visible = TRUE)
  dev <- ggraphics(cont=subwin)
  #### DO NOT KNOW HOW TO DO NEXT...
})
visible(window)<-TRUE
```

Comment: Hi, use the `shiny` and `shinyrgl` package can solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, same comment: to get this done properly would seem torequire something connection between Gtk and openGL that is exposed to the R process. I am unaware of that, though perhaps it is there. It could be worked around by passing around static files and using `gimage`, but I doubt that is what you are after as you would really have to hack in the interactivity.